# mysql STR_TO_DATE() of a variable

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, str-to-date

I'm searching for a method to get all the posts of the last month out of my database. They are saved with the publishing date which is formatted as datetime.

I now defined a variable for last months date:

```
$last_month = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 month"));
```

Now I have to make my SQL Query, which I wrote like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE post_date > STR_TO_DATE($last_month,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Unfortunately this code leaves me with an Error, saying that I have an error in my syntax - which I don't see.
I'm hoping, that anyone of you knows how to solve this little problem. Thans in advance.

Comment: The string is already in the format mysql accepts. Why do you need to use STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: I don't see need to use STR_TO_DATE. Try this: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE post_date > {$last_month}`.

Comment: @ Andre Cardoso: Doesn't work. Gives me this: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '17:11:14' at line 1 42000

Comment: @aynber: The string is not a date format, so sql shouldn't accept it if I'm right...

Comment: Please post your table structure. `post_date` what kind of field is?

Comment: @fusion3k: Type: datetype
Default: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: You need quotes around the variable. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE post_date > '{$last_month}'`  (single or double quotes as needed. Binding parameters work better here)

Comment: So the query must be `"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE post_date > '$last_month'"`

Comment: Thanks so much!! Works just fine.